# Is it unethical to ask an unemployed academic to be an unpaid co-author of a book?

Tags: ethics, authorship

This story happened to me over 30 years ago.

Comment: Just to clarify, you say that you "had no choice but to accept this ruling". Do you mean that you were simply unsuccessful in changing their minds about financial compensation or that you were coerced in some way to proceed, or do you mean something else?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "unethical"? "Unethical" spans a wide range: some people consider common practices like assigning expensive textbooks to be unethical, while others reserve the term for serious misconduct that could have professional consequences (e.g., data fabrication).

Comment: @JW I went to university administrators and asked them whether there was a financial programme under which I could be paid for my collaboration. There wasn't.

Comment: @cag51 "Unethical" in the sense that a person of influence and power uses his influence to request and get a favor from a person who is in a much weaker position. The favor is free because it is implied that there might be future benefits for the weaker side; however these suggested benefits may never materialize.

Comment: This is not a question, this is a rant. Much of this could have been avoided if OP asks a simple question of his supervisors before starting the project or in the first few years. Also, very few of us have reliable information about the academic job market in the Netherlands 30 years ago or OPs accomplishments, so it is hard to judge what the professor could have realistically offer. Academics are often asked to work for free left and right - it is up to you if you take the offer, we cannot fix it for you 30 years later.

Comment: I understand _why_ you think what they did is unethical, my question is _what_ do you want us to tell you? Do you just want to hear us say "yeah, those guys were unethical jerks, they took advantage of you"? Or are you asking us to assess whether they violated professional ethical standards and you could get them in trouble? As it is, I'm rather inclined to agree with Greg that is more of a rant than a question.

Answer (score 3):

Asking isn't unethical, but coercion is. Even offering you an unpaid participation isn't unethical. Academic books always have an uncertain, but generally very small, financial payback. The exceptions are notable.

But if they held something over you or demanded your participation lest they withhold some required service, then that would be unethical. But you don't indicate that such was the case.

So, I'd guess it was poor etiquette not to share, but not unethical.

An explicit acknowledgement should have been provided within the book, but you are a bit unclear if that happened.

Comment: In the Netherlands there is a big difference between working for free as a volunteer (e.g. for a political party, or in an animal shelter), and being asked to do work for free in your own profession. The latter is considered exploitation. This aspect of Labor Law is of course enshrined in the university regulations.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, I guess I wouldn't say *asking* is unethical, as they had no power over you (in the sense of approving your thesis, getting you a job), they told you they were offering nothing in return.

However, if they asked you to *co-author* a book, that to me suggests you at least should receive your name on the cover and royalties. Not affording you those is yes, unethical.

Comment: A miljonair has a friend who is an unemployed handyman. The miljonair asks his friend to perform repairs on his mansion. The miljonair proposes that the work is done for free, for tax reasons etc. In my opinion that is an unethical proposal.

Comment: @M.Wind What does "unethical" mean here? What are the consequences for someone who makes an unethical ask? Yes, it's rude to ask either the scenario in your question or to ask someone to do their job, but they just say "No." and that's that. As Buffy put it, it's *coercion* that's unethical. Your question doesn't describe you as being coerced, it describes you agreeing to work on a book for free to bolster your chances of getting a job. I think you should have said no. They probably shouldn't have asked, but all the cards were on the table (that you weren't getting paid), so I'm not sure them

Comment: Please read the POSTSCRIPT that I added to my piece. The official from Leiden University had no difficulty understanding what "ethics" and "integrity" mean for a professor at a university in the Netherlands.

Comment: @M.Wind Sounds good. What did you ask for, then?

Comment: I asked the university for their opinion. The official of the Physics Department agreed with me that the two professors should not have acted in this manner. I accepted his answer and decided not to follow up on the matter.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I am pleased to see a Freudian typo in oyur answer "asking is unethical. Leaving you off the author list was".

Necessary disclaimer: I like the freudian typo concept, although I think Freud just put altogether a lot of rambling with no scientific basis.

Comment: @EarlGrey How is that Freudian? haha

Comment: from the other comments, the only way your comment can be consistent is saying "asking is *not* unethical".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freudian_slip

Comment: @EarlGrey Oh, I guess. I deleted it to avoid the confusion.